# Timing problem in React.js for display content from api express.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a timing problem in React.js

I have a component that checks the user's valid. Token and user type and if is admin display content and if is not displays " you don't have permission".

But when the user is an admin at first component shows " you don't have permission" and immediately displays the content

I think its an asynchronous problem because it takes some time to get user type from the backend, how to fix this in React.js

My component looks like this:

```
export default function Component() {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(`http://${process.env.REACT_APP_RUN}:3001/api/token/status`, {
        token,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setvalidtoken(response.data);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!token || validtoken.valid === "false") {
    window.location.replace(`http://${process.env.REACT_APP_RUN}:3000/login`);
  } else if (validtoken.type !== "admin") {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="premission-denied-holder">
          <div className="premission-denied-ithed">
            <h6 className="text-premisson">you dont have premission</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <h1>some content here</h1>;
  }
}
```

I tried to change the sequence

Comment: If you are not using the loader then please use it till your API gets successful so that your loader will be visible at the place of " you don't have permission ".

Comment: You can add a component showing 'is loading' during the API request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest for you to add a state isloading:

```
export default function Component() {
  const [isLoading,SetIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    SetIsLoading(false)
    axios
      .post(`http://${process.env.REACT_APP_RUN}:3001/api/token/status`, {
        token,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setvalidtoken(response.data);
        setIsLoading(true)
      });
  }, []);
if(isLoading){
  if (!token || validtoken.valid === "false") {
    window.location.replace(`http://${process.env.REACT_APP_RUN}:3000/login`);
  } else if (validtoken.type !== "admin") {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="premission-denied-holder">
          <div className="premission-denied-ithed">
            <h6 className="text-premisson">you dont have premission</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <h1>some content here</h1>;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track whether the API request is finished or not. You could either add a new piece of state called something like `isLoading` that defaults to `true` and is set to `false` when the API call finishes and use that to show a loading placeholder, or you could maybe just return early if `validtoken` is not yet set (assuming that it is undefined until it is set in the API call).

```
if (!validtoken) return <p>Loading...</p>
```